# javascriptを用いたcookieの削除ができない

Tags: javascript, http, cookie

javascriptを用いてサイトのcookieをすべて削除できるブックマークレットを作成したいと考えております。(デベロッパーツールのcookieのサイト名を右クリックして出てくる「削除」と同じ動きです。)
ブラウザのコンソールで動作確認をしている中,

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

を用いて存在するcookieの確認はできたのですが、それ以降は手つかずの状態です。

```
document.cookie = "name=; max-age=0";
document.cookie = "name=; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
```

これらのコードを用いれば良いというところまではわかりましたが、これを実行してももとからサイトで設定されているcookieが削除できません。
また一律にcookieを削除する方法もわかりません。
どなたかご教授頂けますと幸いです。

---

以下の画像を例に説明させていただきます。
こちらのcookieは `HttpOnly` 属性はついておりませんし、再設定されるcookieでもありませんが、削除できません。

[image: 件の画像です]

---

javascriptでDeveloperToolのApplicationタブ、Storage / Cookies の下のサイト名(このページだとja.stackoverflow.com)を右クリックすると出てくる「削除」を実行できるようなスクリプトを作成したいと思っております。
単一の指定されたcookieの削除についてはsayuriさんの回答などから把握できましたがが、一括削除については手つかずです。
どうかご教授の方よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「うまく実行できません」が何を行い、何を見てこの判断されたのかがよくわかりませんでした。この部分が問題の核心なような気がします。

Comment: 既に回答済みの質問文を削除されてしまうとQ&Aが成立しなくなります。すみませんが以前の質問文を復活させていただきました。今後は答えて欲しい内容を尋ねるようお願いします。

Comment: 「もとからサイトで設定されているcookie」って何ですか？

Comment: document.cookie を利用して Coookie を設定する際 path を省略すると、クッキーがブラウザに保存される時そのページのディレクトリがパスに設定されます。パスが違うという問題では？

Comment: @WebSurfer ご指摘ありがとうございます。そちらにつきましては解決済みです。問題は一括削除のやり方です。

Comment: 「もとからサイトで設定されているcookie」って何ですか？

Comment: @WebSurfer ```document.cookie = "name=;```などで自分で後で設定した以外のcookieです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> もとからサイトで設定されているcookieが削除できません。

「何を見てこの判断されたのかがよくわかりませんでした。」と指摘しました。どのような操作を行い、cookieが削除できていないと判断したのか、操作方法がわからなければ対処方法も提示できないわけですが、通じなかったのでしょうか？

---

とりあず [HTTP Cookie の使用](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) をよく読み理解してください。

例えば、Webサーバーはレスポンスに `Set-Cookie` ヘッダーを含めることでブラウザーに対してcookieを書き込むことができます。更に `HttpOnly` 属性を含めることでブラウザーに対してJavaScriptからの操作を認めない指定も可能です。

というわけで、 `document.cookie` で見えているものについては質問文の方法で削除可能ですが、その場合は `document.cookie` は空になるはずですし、Webサーバーからのレスポンスで改めて `Set-Cookie` されれば復活します。

---

開発者ツールを参照されているようなので、 **Application**タブの**Storage** /  **Cookies** を確認ください。
cookieは名前だけでなく`domain`と`path`の情報があり、３つ合わせた複合キーになっています。
例示されました`OptanonConsent`ですと

- Name: `OptanonConsent`
- Domain: `.stackoverflow.com`
- Path: `/`

となっています。このため、`OptanonConsent`を編集するためには

```
document.cookie = "OptanonConsent=;domain=.stackoverflow.com;path=/;";
```

と３つのキーを一致させた上で、値を変更してください。削除されるのであれば、max-ageやexpiresなど。

---

> 単一の指定されたcookieの削除についてはsayuriさんの回答などから把握できましたがが、一括削除については手つかずです。

残念ながら方法はありません。もちろん、`document.cookie`を参照することで、Name部分を把握することはできますが、DomainとPathを知ることができないため、削除できないです。

Comment: すみません。ご指摘の文章を正しく理解しておりませんでした。質問を修正させていただきました。

Comment: @初心者 更新された質問文を踏まえて、問題となっているcookieの編集方法を加筆しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。単一のcookieについては無事削除が行えました。 Storage / Cookiesのほうはすでに参照していました。先にそれを書けばよかったと後悔しているのですが、Storage / Cookies の下のサイト名(ja.stackoverflow.com)を右クリックすると出てくる「削除」を実行できるようなスクリプトを作成したく、このような質問をさせていただきました。

Comment: @初心者 そう質問文に書けばいいのではないでしょうか？